# When installing VSCode via Flatpak, where is its `code` executable located?

Tags: flatpak, visual-studio-code

When installing Visual Studio Code via apt or homebrew, the VSCode `code` executable goes to a standard location that is within `PATH`, however it seems when installing VSCode via Flatpak, it goes somewhere special. I am trying to find this location such that I can add it to my `PATH`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how flatpack works; the executable is hidden in a container and you need to set up the whole environment to be able to call it. Delivering a well-isolated, not-to-be-run-from-outside environment is the whole point.

You'll want to [`flatpack run app-name`](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html#flatpak-run) to run your application – in your case, probably `flatpak run com.visualstudio.code`; you cann add arguments as you want, they will be forwarded to the executable the flatpack declares as the application to run.

Comment: Okay thank you. I'll need to do some thinking then on how to apply that to things like `git config --global core.editor`

Comment: should be really `flatpack run com.visualstudio.code --wait`, far as I know, never tried. (`--wait` is really important.)